# What is meant by the statement "Data is inactive but information is active"?

Tags: c++

I came across the statement "data is inactive but information is active" while reading differences between data and information. What is meant by this statement?

Comment: Can you cite the source where you read this?  What is the surrounding context?

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: This question is probably better for philosophy. Data consists of the state of some thing. That thing, [some think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemological_realism), can just be. Now, to have information you need to interact with with what contains the data to read the data. In addition, you need to interpret the data according to some encoding. The same data can be interpreted as different piece of information depending on the encoding. For example, a bit of data, can be interpreted as $0$ or $1$, or as `True` or `False`, or as $12312$ or $\star$.

Comment: Honestly it sounds like content-free handwaving to me.